# fql for retrieving friends who has got app installed

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-fql

What would be the fql query for getting friends who has got certain application installed and has accepted given permissions and are girls?

here is my query so far:

```
 $fql = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";
    $response = $facebook->api(array(
        'method' => 'fql.query',
        'query' =>$fql,
    ));
    $this->_helper->json($response);
```

Comment: accepted given perrmisions means what? Which permissions you want to check?

Answer (score 1):

Try this fql query:

> $fql = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square, sex FROM user WHERE sex='female'
>   AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";